# CefSharp ppapi plugin process crashed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

The configuration of my project;

- CefSharp version : 75.0.3770.100
- PepFlashPlayer version : 32.0.0.371
- .NET 4.0.30319

The application randomly crashes, displaying a blank flash image.
Here is the debug.log.:

```
[1115/080911.530:VERBOSE1:ppapi_plugin_process_host.cc(490)] PpapiPluginProcessHost::OnChannelError()
[1115/080911.530:VERBOSE1:ppapi_plugin_process_host.cc(459)] ppapi plugin process crashed.
[1115/081010.266:VERBOSE1:statistics_recorder.cc(410)] Collections of all histograms
```

I cannot upgrade CefSharp because my application still relies on the Flash plugin.

Some of my existing CefSettings :

```
settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-npapi", "1");
//Enable NPAPI plugs which were disabled by default in Chromium 43 (NPAPI will be removed completely in Chromium 45)

currentPath = String.Format(@"C:\ProgramData\CefSharpTest");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", 
Path.Combine(currentPath, "pepflashplayer.dll"));
```

Comment: Perhaps give https://github.com/Mzying2001/CefFlashBrowser a try, see if that works. From a `CefSharp` point of view, there's no support for flash (or versions that old).

Comment: i see, btw i thought pepperflash version 32.O.O.371 is the last version before end off life. i will try this version 34.O.O.192 first. Thank You so much for your answer @amaitland.